# docker build run paused ,can any one help me

Tags: docker

its very strange,when i run docker build ,process paused,just as follows:

```
docker build -t registry.ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com/joyours_dev/cronjobonlinebackgroundtask:v1 -f  Dockerfile.prod  .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  25.14MB
Step 1/13 : FROM nginx
 ---> c316d5a335a5
Step 2/13 : COPY ./app  /home/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b3b5594156ff
Step 3/13 : WORKDIR /home
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9fcfe5da215
Step 4/13 : ARG PROJECT_DIR=/var/petaplay/simplethai
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fa19c2174392
Step 5/13 : ARG MICROSERVICE_DIR=/var/petaplay/simplethai/microservice/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c086111be060
Step 6/13 : ARG SERVICE_NAME=onlineservice
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e0e2035a756b
Step 7/13 : RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR/common/config
 ---> Running in 9b38ed579980
```

console stop at Step 7/13，

Comment: Try a build with no cache `docker build -t registry.ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com/joyours_dev/cronjobonlinebackgroundtask:v1 --no-cache -f  Dockerfile.prod  .`

Comment: its not working,`docker build --no-cache -t registry.ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com/joyours_dev/activity5:v1 `, process stucked at `Step 7/13 : RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR/common/config`